# urlfetchapp file size

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, urlfetch

I'm currently trying to make a Google Apps Script that would download the new issues of a free online magazine I read directly to Google Drive every 2 months. Unfortunately, the UrlFetchApp seems to have a file size limit somewhere between 5 MB and 10 MB, unfortunately the PDF files range from 5 MB to 20 MB, meaning some issues are not downloaded and return a "Content too large" error.

I know its only one file every 2 months so I could do it manually but I was wondering if there was a way to download "large" files directly to Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard), the limit is 50 MB per day for consumer accounts

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that.

Unfortunately there seems to also be a limit of 10 MB per file (UrlFetch Post Size).

Would there be a way to split the file download?